# Tortoise svn Folder restrict to users

Tags: tortoisesvn

User Created 3 folders in SVN,in that some people have access to all folders.User created another sub folder from folder1 for that particular sub folder he want authorization.

please help on this.

Regards,
Nageswari

Answer (score 0):

You would need to include [Path-Based Authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html). You can limit permissions to the folder through the authz file. So let's say you have a directory structure such as:

```
Repo/trunk
|_ Folder1
   |_ Sub-folder  
|_ Folder2
|_ Folder3
```

You would set your permissions file like this:

```
[groups]
x-group = Nageswari, Chris
y-group = User3

[Repo:/trunk]
@x-group = rw
@y-group = rw

[Repo:/trunk/Folder1/Sub-folder]
@x-group = 
@y-group = rw
```

Where the line `@x-group =` essentially forbids a certain group (or you can specify a user as well) from accessing that directory. (In all honesty, the line underneath that: `@y-group = rw` is actually redundant because it would inherently receive those permissions for `y-group` from the trunk.. But for brevity sake you can keep it in).