# Feasibility to block deletion option for all Engineers and providing the same only to Admin

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I want to disable the delete option for all the users having access for the particular path that will be enable for only admin.

We are using SVN server as-Visual svn server version-3.6.0
Tortoise svn server-1.9.5 version

Comment: Is there any reason why you keep asking a different variation of the same question? Did [the answerer on your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53668626/5879778) not help provide insight to what you're trying to accomplish? ([Which was the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53615951/5879778) I also gave you on another question of yours?). [Or your most previous 
 answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53652851/5879778)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to show delete option for a user if he has created particular folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53668309/i-want-to-show-delete-option-for-a-user-if-he-has-created-particular-folder)